# Locksmith integration with Algolia

Tags: shopify-app, ip-restrictions

Integration with Locksmith (shopify app) with Algolia

Is there a direct integration or workaround to integrate Algolia with Locksmith. Trying to achieve restricted access to pages for specific users.

any steps are appreciated!

nothing yet tried yet

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.